# How to check the both option:selected and radio input :checked at once in different divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

these are the codes I initially used

```
var value_price = jQuery('option:selected', this).attr('value_price');
var value_price = jQuery("input[name='style']:checked", this).attr('value_price');
```

and tried the following but it doesn't support every situation.

```
var value_price = (jQuery('option:selected', this)
    .attr('value_price'))?jQuery('option:selected', this)
    .attr('value_price'):jQuery("input[name='style']:checked", this)
    .attr('value_price');
```

Please help me to solve it out

Comment: Please share any errors that are shown, and what you want to do? And it also seems you are using an old version of jQuery

Comment: I was trying to convert 2 out of 5 select tags to radio input the error was not in the JS tha exact values were not passing when i am passing to the server

Comment: can you please help to convert the above select tag to a radio input

Comment: <select name="{{ $attributes_data['option']['id'] }}" class="var-drop currentstock attributeid_<?=$index++?>" attributeid = "$var"> 
<option @if(in_array($values_data['id'],$value_ids)) selected @endif attributes_value="{{ $values_data['products_attributes_id'] }}" value="{{ $values_data['id'] }}" prefix = '{{ $values_data['price_prefix'] }}' value_price ="{{ $values_data['price']+0 }}" >{{ $values_data['value'] }}</option> 
</select>

Comment: you shoud show your html generated.... with all input and option tag.

Comment: <select name="2" onchange="getQuantity()" class="var-drop currentstock attributeid_1" attributeid="2">
    <option selected="" attributes_value="20" value="5" prefix="+" value_price="0">Small</option>
     <option selected="" attributes_value="21" value="6" prefix="+" value_price="0">Medium</option>                                                              
    <option attributes_value="27" value="8" prefix="+" value_price="200">XL</option>
</select>

Comment: I want to convert the above select tag to radio option as follows

Comment: <label class="image-selector">
    <input type="radio" name="1" name="style" attributeid="1" attributes_value="22" value="1" prefix="+" value_price="20">
    <span class="imagebox">
        <img src="/images/media/2020/12/T5YSn19111.jpg" title="Red">
    </span>
</label>
<label class="image-selector">
    <input type="radio" name="1" name="style"  attributeid="1" attributes_value="26" value="3" prefix="+" value_price="1">
    <span class="imagebox">
        <img src="/images/media/2020/12/cv1rs19611.jpg" title="Sky Blue">
    </span>
</label>